# Loop function calling async function

Tags: 2010, jsom

Someone mentioned that calling cascaded async functions don't work. However I'm trying a simple test with a for-next loop and getting unpredictable results. The console.log always shows the last item but all the items get created. Is there something wrong with the way I'm reporting the ID?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function btnSubmit_OnClientClick() {

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    create(i);
        }
console.log('completed main code');
}


function create(i) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestPromises');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Item '+ i );

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.SaveEmployeeSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.SaveEmployeeFailure));

}


function SaveEmployeeSuccess() {
console.log('item created'+oListItem.get_id());
}

function SaveEmployeeFailure() {

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading async functions do work, since your example is working fine. It's only how your are handling responses that's problematic.

It looks like the problem is how you are referencing `oListItem`.

Each time you iterate though the loop you are changing the same reference to oListItem since in your case `this.oListItem` is a global variable. try using `var oListItem` instead and then passing the reference to the item into your success method in some manner.

Edit, here's a working example:

```
function create(i) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SomeList');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    //note that we are using var to make a local variable.
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Item '+ i );
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    var SaveEmployeeSuccess = function() {
        console.log('item created'+this.get_id());
    }

    var SaveEmployeeFailure = function() {};
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(oListItem, SaveEmployeeSuccess), 
        Function.createDelegate(oListItem, SaveEmployeeFailure));

}
```

Comment: Orange Juice confirmed that the items are created as expected which proves that async works in loop. I think his question was why only the last item id is printed when all items are created correctly! I don't think you answered his actual question! I think you need to be clear about 'try using var oListItem instead and then passing the reference to the item into your success method in some manner.'

Comment: Yes, that answered the question! Thanks. Up Vote for you!

Comment: I've tried the code as Gilgamesh suggested and receive an error in the success method - 'oListItem' is undefined -

Comment: I changed the name of the list in my example so that might be the problem you have.

Comment: I'm attempting to log the items created to the console from within the success callback function. This is where the error occurs.

Comment: My methodology to test was to create the method i posted above and then run the `btnSubmit_OnClientClick()` method from your question, the output for me is correct and  it logs "completed main code" then then the log messages for items 1-3 being created.

Comment: When you say cascading async functions work, my example doesn't demonstrate it well. If I had loop in a success method which triggered another function that also contained an async method, will this not cause issues? I done this previously, and had to use an array in the 1st loop which fed into the 2nd async function.

Comment: I simply wrote code that corrected the very minor error you had in your post. In theory doing a bunch of async operations won't cause issues. however once you want to handle responses to async operations you will have to write code that deals with it. This is larger topic and there's lots of information on how to do async things with javascript, for example [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are one way that this is often handled.